# Installing Boost C++ on Mac OS X Capitan

Tags: macos, boost, caffe

I am trying to install the boost C++ library as a dependency for Caffe on Mac OS X EL Capitan. I have tried to build from source using

```
brew install --build-from-source --fresh -vd boost boost-python
```

but the build process never passes the below stage for almost a day.

[image]

So, I have tried installing the pre-packaged version using just

```
brew install boost
```

this time it stops at the below stage for more than 2 hours.

[image]

Any help or work around for this problem is really appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

**Update:**

I figured out that for me there is a problem installing boost 1.57.0 either from source or the pre-packaged version.

So, I did `brew update` then
 `brew install --fresh boost boost-python` and that solved it. However, installing with --build-from-souce option still gets stuck.